# Separate \arraystretch value for every table

Tags: tables, spacing

`\arraystretch` defines vertical spacing of tables. If I have several tables, how can I define a separate value of `\arraystretch` for every table? In my case, the last defined `\arraystretch` works for all tables.

Comment: I would suggest accepting answers to some of the questions you have asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The presented solutions have a limitation in that they disallow the vertical alignment optional argument to `tabular`.

Here is a version much more flexible that supports `tabular`, `tabular*`, `array` and also `longtable` (if the relative package is loaded).

If the `width` key is set, `tabular*` is used. Otherwise the type of tabular is determined by the `type` key (default `tabular`). Note that the stretch is reset to 1 at each call. It would be possible to define a “inherit” key so the stretch factor is preserved in nested tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{xparse} % only needed for LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{flexitab}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { flexitab }
   {
    % default value for type
    type = tabular,
    % default value for stretch
    stretch = 1,
    % default value for alignment
    align = c,
    % default value for width
    width = -1000pt,
    #1
   }
  \dim_compare:nTF { \l_flexitab_width_dim > -1pt }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_flexitab_type_tl { tabular* }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_flexitab_start_tl { \begin{tabular*}{\l_flexitab_width_dim} }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_flexitab_start_tl { \begin{\l_flexitab_type_tl} }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l_flexitab_start_tl
   {
    [\l_flexitab_align_tl]{\exp_not:V \l_flexitab_columns_tl}
   }
  \tl_set_eq:NN \arraystretch \l_flexitab_stretch_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_flexitab_start_tl
 }
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF {\l_flexitab_type_tl}{tabular*}
   { \end{tabular*} }
   { \end{\l_flexitab_type_tl} }
 }

\keys_define:nn { flexitab }
 {
  type    .tl_set:N  = \l_flexitab_type_tl,
  align   .tl_set:N  = \l_flexitab_align_tl,
  width   .dim_set:N = \l_flexitab_width_dim,
  columns .tl_set:N  = \l_flexitab_columns_tl,
  stretch .tl_set:N  = \l_flexitab_stretch_tl,
 }
\tl_new:N \l_flexitab_start_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{flexitab}{
  stretch=2,
  columns=cc,
}
AA & BBB \\
AA & BBB \\
C  & \begin{flexitab}{columns=@{}l@{},align=t}D\\D\\D\end{flexitab}
\end{flexitab}

\bigskip

\bigskip
$\begin{flexitab}{
  type=array,
  columns=cc,
}
aa & bb \\
cc & \begin{flexitab}{stretch=2,columns=l,align=b}aa \\ bb \\ccc\end{flexitab} \\
d & d
\end{flexitab}$

\noindent
\begin{flexitab}{
  stretch=2,
  width=\textwidth,
  columns=@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll@{},
}
AAAA & BBBB \\
CC   & DDD
\end{flexitab}

\bigskip

\begin{flexitab}{
  type=longtable,
  columns=cc
}
aa & bb \\
\hline
\endhead
cc & dd \\
cc & dd \\
cc & dd \\
cc & dd \\
\end{flexitab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It has a deprecated used of `str_if_eq_x_nnTF', I think (but I don't know much LaTeX3).

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Thanks, I’ll replace the deprecated function.

Answer (score 71):

If you define `\arraystretch` direct before the table (i.e. `tabular`) inside a group it should only be active for this table.

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{<value>}
\begin{tabular}{...}
 ...
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
```

Or define your own environment:

```
\renewenvironment{mytabular}[1][1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{#1}%
  \tabular%
}{%
  \endtabular
}

% ...

\begin{mytabular}[<stretch value>]{...}
 ...
\end{mytabular}
```

Comment: @MartinScharrer why do you use the `*` with the `\renewcommand`?

Comment: @MarioS.E.: The starred version defines a "normal" macro, while the normal version defines a "long" macro which may contain `\par`. This is not required for `\arraystretch` so I used the starred version. This however is just a very minor difference and does not have a real impact here.

Comment: could you restore the old value after the table? So that the following tables are not affected.

Comment: @FrederickNord: As the changes are done inside a group they will not be valid afterwards. All changes in a group (which are not done globally) are automatically restored at the end of the group by TeX.

Answer (score 19):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{Tabular}[2][1]
  {\def\arraystretch{#1}\tabular{#2}}
  {\endtabular}

\begin{document}

\begin{Tabular}{ccc}
 c & c & C\\
 c & c & C
\end{Tabular}

\begin{Tabular}[3]{ccc}
 c & c & C\\
 c & c & C
\end{Tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it worked. thank you. another question, e.g., how can i define a new command to use the new environment `Tabular` in the above example? i want to know how i can transfer parameters of `\newcommand` to `\newenvironment`.

Comment: @warem: there is no difference to the above example where I passed an argument from the environment to a command. However, to give a more explicitly answer, create an example of what you really want to do. Maybe as a new question.

Comment: i mean create a new command to use the `Tabular` environmet. e.g., `\newcommand{\test}[2]{\begin{Tabular}[2]...\end{Tabular}}`. it didn't work. it seemed that the parameters of `test` command can't be transferred to `Tabular` correctly.

Comment: @warem: `\newcommand{\test}[2]{\begin{Tabular}{#1}#2\end{Tabular}}` It depends to the menaing of #1 and #2

Comment: @warem consider accept the answer if so

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the table enviroment to place your tables  floats you can just redefine arraystretch within that environment without affecting other tables:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.95}
    \caption{table 1}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        c & c & C\\
        c & c & C
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{table 2}
    \begin{tabular}[3]{ccc}
     c & c & C\\
     c & c & C
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```